# How do I find the complex solutions to the equation $(z+2i)^4 = 16$ using roots of the equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider this complex equation

$$(z+2i)^4 = 16$$
Now I want to find all of the complex solutions to this equation.For that I tried finding all of the roots and than finding the appropriate solutions.

Find the roots using this formula $$ w_k = \sqrt[n]{r} \space e^{i+(\phi k\pi)/n} $$

Where n is 4 and and k = n-1 and r = 16

Now since I do not have an argument; 16 is by it self I tried using Eulers Identity $$ e^{\pi i} +1 = 0 $$

I can rearange this equation to be $$ 1 = -e^{\pi i}$$ and I can write 16 as 16 * 1

After plugging it into the formula for k = 0 I get this

$$ w_1 = \sqrt[n]{-16} \space e^{\pi/4} $$  Try to simplify

$$ w_1 = -4i * (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}i}{2}) $$ Simplify more I get

$$ w_1 = 2\sqrt{2}(2-1) $$

To get the first solution I did $$ z_1 = w_1 -2i $$ And this gives me a even more complicated expression. The answer should be $$ z_1 = 2-2i $$

I am doing something wrong,not sure what. Any insight would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are doing.

---

**Hint**
$$u^4=16\iff u=2e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{4}},\quad k=0,1,2,3.$$
Taking $u=z+2i$ gives you all solutions.

Comment: This is very close to what I am trying to achive. But can you explain what exactly are the steps taken. you first sub 16 for u to the 4th and than proceed to find simply u,hence u need to pull the 4th root of 16 which is 2.but how do you get that e expression? Looking at the general formula it seems that you assumed that the argument is 0.Am I correct in thinking that?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Here is another way to proceed:
\begin{align*}
(z + 2i)^{4} = 16 & \Longleftrightarrow (z + 2i)^{4} - 16 = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow [(z + 2i)^{2}]^{2} - 4^{2} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (z^{2} + 4iz - 4)^{2} - 4^{2} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (z^{2} + 4iz)(z^{2} + 4iz - 8) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z(z + 4i)(z^{2} + 4iz - 8) = 0
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I am assuming I just solve the quadratic equation in the right bracket,and find the zeros in the left?

Comment: @cody1 That's the point.